# Azure schedule tasks through a script

Tags: python, azure

I have an application that I am going to deploy to Microsoft Azure.  The application gives users ability to run a specific task at a certain time, for example "I want to run taskX in 5 minutes" or "I want to run taskX in 1hour25minutes" and after that time, the task should run.

How would I do this in Azure.  I know Azure has a task scheduler, but the problem is I don't see a way to:
1) Set the time of the schedule through a script (application is using python + flask for the backend)
2) Run the task on exactly the supplied time.

What I want to avoid doing is having to do some sort of polling where I check every hour, on the hour for new tasks.  Essentially I want to run the task on the exact time specified. So, if its 11:30 and the user says "I want to run the task in 10 minutes", I would have to wait until 12:00 (for the polling program to check for new tasks).  What I would like is, if it is "11:30" and the user says "I want to run the task in 10 minutes", it will run at "11:40".

Thank you very much, help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) Scheduler is available in Python:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-mgmt-scheduler

There is unfortunately no a lot of samples for that client, but you can start with:
https://learn.microsoft.com/python/azure/

2) I'm not expert in the Scheduler API, but it seems to me you should be able to achieve this. See documentation for reference on this part:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-get-started-portal

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, Azure Scheduler may not satisfy your scenario.

If you want to add the feature for your flask app on Azure Web Apps like Linux `crontab`, per my experience, I think you can try to use some Python libraries like [`python-crontab`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab/) to do it.

Or the other needs I guess, you just want to create a job in Python to run it via Python script or only schedule a time to make it works, maybe the feature `triggered job` of WebJobs on Azure WebApp is suitable with this and via WebJob API to run it. Please see more details about [WebJobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) to create a triggered job or invoke it.

Hope it helps.